# Object is freezed cannot be modified

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using passportJS for authentication. If user get register, I create token for the user but the issue is I can't modify or change the object eg.

```
exports.register = function(req, res, callback) {
passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, message) {
    if (err)
        return callback(err);

    if (!user)
        return callback({status: 400, message: message});

    autorization.createToken(user, function(err, token) {
        if (err)
            return callback(err);
        var userData = {}; //<Issue is its not editable I can't append or delete from this.>
        userData = user;
        delete userData.password;
        userData["token"] = token;
        console.log(userData);
        console.log(token);
        return callback(null, user);
    });
})(req, res, callback);
};
```

Now issue is though token is generating. I am received token in callback. but I can't change value for user object that is return. What I want is once token is created it append on key token and returns to user.

```
exports.createToken = function(user, callback) {
var token = jwt.sign( //        { _id: user._id, email: user.email, password: user.password}
    user, config.superSecret, {
        expiresInMinutes: config.expJwtMin
    });
return callback(null, token);
};
```

Comment: If i understand, you want to return a copy of user, with the token added ?

Comment: can you not just do user.token = token?

Comment: @SKY: or `user_cpy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)); user_cpy.token = token; ` if he doesn't have to modify 'user' in the callback, and if user can be stringified.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant sure, if he does not want to modify the user, then he can clone the object as well using Object.assign({},user)

Comment: @SKY I already have tried before putting on SOF `user.token = token`

Comment: does the console.log statements you have in your code fragment spit out any output for the token and userData? I also see that you are returning user instead of userData and you have attached token to the userData in your code

Comment: Yes it did. If I console for token value separately it do. But at same moment if I tried to add it to `userData` it doesn't pull the key token to `userData`

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant  - Its done with your logic `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));`. But what was the reason Why I couldn't modify the same user object

Comment: @Sankalp: I think it's due to `autorization.createToken` which requires user to not change.

Comment: I modified question please check. this function doesn't contain any logic to freeze object.